# HTML: unwanted whitespace

Tags: css, html, header, containers, whitespace

I'm trying to teach myself html and css through/by creating a portfolio. The problem is when I create a container for my logo and nav menu inside the header and adjust the browser size by zooming into the max. It creates unwanted whitespace on the right of the html. What’s the best method in avoiding these types of issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/nt3HA/
http://jsfiddle.net/nt3HA/embedde

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="innernav"> 
<div id="container"> 
<img src="images/ARlogo2.png" alt="ARlogo" id="logo"> 
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- #header -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

css

```
    html,
body{
            margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

    #wrapper{
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
}

    #header{
        background: #242424;
}

    #innernav{ 
        padding: 20px 0;
}

    #container{
        margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 1040px;;
}

    #logo{
        position: relative;
}

    #content{
        padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}

    #footer{
       background:#222222;
       width:100%;
       height:100px;
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
       left:0;
}
```

Comment: You wrote `wrapper` two times. Is it a typo?

Comment: I don't know what your aiming to do. The whitespace is only there because your image have not the width of 1040px. You can use `background-size: 100%`, but that will blur your image.

Comment: @DMS did your issue get resolved? You must provide a feedback to the answerers after they post an answer.

Comment: @bilal yes its a typo

Comment: @Ranveer I've just checked the messages now, just waiting for a response now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `container`, set `width:100%` instead of `1040px`.

```
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It works. Here's your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nt3HA/1/

Comment: I've placed width: 100%; and within the css file the id #logo I've placed left: 30%; and also tried left: 300px it still creates some whitespace on the right when you zoomed into the max on the html page. Also I've tried lowering the width to 80% and adding the nav menu using the <ul> tag but it seems to create white space on the right of the html page when you zoomed in to the max. I've been researching portfolios and notices these websites don't have white space when zoomed into the max: http://www.suzannejworthington.com/    http://www.andpeople.co.za/ http://www.christhurman.com/

Comment: That is because the websites you've seen are responsive. And most probably they use `@media` tags.

Comment: @DMS Also, can you show me a fiddle of the problem you are currently facing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2FMAG/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/2FMAG/1/embedded/result/, ok its not letting me place a dummy image for my logo AR media, the size of the AR media logo is width: 377px and height: 143px

Comment: I removed your `#container #nav li` `padding` and it worked. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/2FMAG/2/

Comment: Again, I would suggest using a responsive framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.getbotstrap.com)

Answer (score 0):

In on line of modification , Give container width: auto will remove extra  right space!

```
 #container{width:auto;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3HA/2/)

Comment: I've tried placing width:auto; and then adding the nav menu using the <ul> tag but it still creates white space when I try to adjust the nav menu use position: relative and left: 100px;. How do portfolios such as suzannejworthington.com andpeople.co.za christhurman.com avoid the whitespace?

Comment: can you please update your jsfiddle page for more precision ?

Comment: working perfectly without media queries :  http://jsfiddle.net/nt3HA/5/   have a nice day !

Comment: Ok I've tried adjusting it a little more but it keeps creating whitespace on the right side of the html page when you zoom into the max http://jsfiddle.net/ry7a2/   http://jsfiddle.net/ry7a2/embedded/result/